# Node xslt-processor does not transform my XML

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I am trying to transform an XML input using an XSLT file but it's only outputting the root tags. I am using the node module xslt-processor to keep it browser-agnostic.

When I test with a [small example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XSLTProcessor/Basic_Example), the transformation works as expected.

The XML and XSLT files I'm working with are below, and this is the output:

`<Bundle xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"/>`

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/spl/stylesheet/spl.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<document xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hl7-org:v3 https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/spl/schema/spl.xsd">
  <id root="fadc3edf-d17c-42a0-8e3a-1a1d6eaf07a4"/>
  <code code="51726-8" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" displayName="NDC/NHRIC LABELER CODE REQUEST"/>
  <effectiveTime value="20220120"/>
  <setId root="f3ee38c6-4523-4fff-86fb-8d14de6652c4"/>
  <versionNumber value="2"/>
  <author>
    <time/>
    <assignedEntity>
      <representedOrganization>
        <id root="1.3.6.1.4.1.519.1" extension="245621042"/>
        <id root="2.16.840.1.113883.6.69" extension="15365"/>
        <name>National Pharma of Australia Inc.</name>
        <contactParty>
          <addr>
            <country>AUS</country>
            <state>Telangana</state>
            <city>RangareddyDistrict</city>
            <postalCode>500001</postalCode>
            <streetAddressLine>Plot 101 First Street</streetAddressLine>
          </addr>
          <telecom value="tel:+9-140-111-2222"/>
          <telecom value="mailto:jdoe_1@npoiinc.net"/>
          <contactPerson>
            <name>Mr. John Doe_1</name>
          </contactPerson>
        </contactParty>
        <assignedEntity>
          <assignedOrganization>
            <assignedEntity>
              <assignedOrganization>
                <id root="1.3.6.1.4.1.519.1" extension="245621042"/>
                <name>National Pharma of Australia Inc.</name>
                <addr>
                  <country>AUS</country>
                  <state>Telangana</state>
                  <city>RangareddyDistrict</city>
                  <postalCode>500002</postalCode>
                  <streetAddressLine>Plot 102 Village Ave</streetAddressLine>
                </addr>
                <assignedEntity>
                  <assignedOrganization>
                    <id root="1.3.6.1.4.1.519.1" extension="398988034"/>
                    <name>New National Pharma of Australia Inc. US Agent</name>
                    <telecom value="tel:+1-908-999-1213"/>
                    <telecom value="mailto:jdoe_3@npoiinc.net"/>
                  </assignedOrganization>
                  <performance>
                    <actDefinition>
                      <code code="C73330" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.3.26.1.1" displayName="united states agent"/>
                    </actDefinition>
                  </performance>
                </assignedEntity>
              </assignedOrganization>
              <performance>
                <actDefinition>
                  <code code="C43360" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.3.26.1.1" displayName="manufacture"/>
                  <subjectOf>
                    <approval>
                      <code code="C106643" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.3.26.1.1" displayName="Manufactures human prescription drug products"/>
                    </approval>
                  </subjectOf>
                </actDefinition>
              </performance>
            </assignedEntity>
          </assignedOrganization>
        </assignedEntity>
      </representedOrganization>
    </assignedEntity>
  </author>
  <component>
    <structuredBody/>
  </component>
</document>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
This file was generated by Altova MapForce 2021r3

YOU SHOULD NOT MODIFY THIS FILE, BECAUSE IT WILL BE
OVERWRITTEN WHEN YOU RE-RUN CODE GENERATION.

Refer to the Altova MapForce Documentation for further details.
http://www.altova.com/mapforce
-->
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:tbf="http://www.altova.com/MapForce/UDF/tbf" xmlns:user="http://www.altova.com/MapForce/UDF/user" xmlns:vmf="http://www.altova.com/MapForce/UDF/vmf" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:ns0="urn:hl7-org:v3" exclude-result-prefixes="tbf user vmf xs fn ns0">
    <xsl:template name="tbf:tbf2_Simple-CD">
        <xsl:param name="input" select="()"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$input/@code">
            <xsl:attribute name="code" select="fn:string(.)"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="$input/@codeSystem">
            <xsl:attribute name="codeSystem" select="fn:string(.)"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="$input/@displayName">
            <xsl:attribute name="displayName" select="fn:string(.)"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="user:createOrganizationAffiliation">
        <xsl:param name="participatingId" select="()"/>
        <xsl:param name="SimpleCD" select="()"/>
        <OrganizationAffiliation xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir">
            <organization>
                <reference>
                    <xsl:attribute name="value" namespace="" select="'#'"/>
                </reference>
            </organization>
            <participatingOrganization>
                <reference>
                    <xsl:attribute name="value" namespace="" select="$participatingId"/>
                </reference>
            </participatingOrganization>
            <code>
                <coding>
                    <system>
                        <xsl:attribute name="value" namespace="" select="xs:string(xs:anyURI('http://ncicb.nci.nih.gov/xml/owl/EVS/Thesaurus.owl'))"/>
                    </system>
                    <code>
                        <xsl:for-each select="$SimpleCD/@code">
                            <xsl:attribute name="value" namespace="" select="fn:string(.)"/>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </code>
                    <display>
                        <xsl:for-each select="$SimpleCD/@displayName">
                            <xsl:attribute name="value" namespace="" select="fn:string(.)"/>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </display>
                </coding>
            </code>
        </OrganizationAffiliation>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="user:parseTelecom">
        <xsl:param name="SimpleTEL" select="()"/>
        <xsl:variable name="var3_value" as="node()?" select="$SimpleTEL/@value"/>
        <ContactPoint xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir">
            <system>
                <xsl:for-each select="$var3_value">
                    <xsl:attribute name="value" namespace="">
                        <xsl:call-template name="vmf:vmf8_inputtoresult">
                            <xsl:with-param name="input" select="fn:substring-before(xs:string(xs:anyURI(fn:string(.))), ':')" as="xs:string"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </system>
            <value>
                <xsl:for-each select="$var3_value">
                    <xsl:variable name="var2_cur_as_string" as="xs:string" select="xs:string(xs:anyURI(fn:string(.)))"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="var1_resultof_vmf__inputtoresult" as="xs:string">
                        <xsl:call-template name="vmf:vmf8_inputtoresult">
                            <xsl:with-param name="input" select="fn:substring-before($var2_cur_as_string, ':')" as="xs:string"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:attribute name="value" namespace="">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="($var1_resultof_vmf__inputtoresult = 'url')">
                                <xsl:sequence select="$var2_cur_as_string"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:sequence select="fn:substring-after($var2_cur_as_string, ':')"/>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </value>
        </ContactPoint>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="user:createLabelerOrganization">
        <xsl:param name="LabelerOrganization" select="()"/>
        <xsl:variable name="var6_assignedEntity" as="node()*" select="$LabelerOrganization/ns0:assignedEntity"/>
        <xsl:variable name="var7_http___hl__org_fhir_us_spl_Cod_as_string" as="xs:string" select="xs:string(xs:anyURI('http://hl7.org/fhir/us/spl/CodeSystem/codesystem-organizationTypes'))"/>
        <Organization xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir">
            <xsl:for-each select="$var6_assignedEntity/ns0:assignedOrganization/ns0:assignedEntity/ns0:performance">
                <xsl:variable name="var1_actDefinition" as="node()*" select="ns0:actDefinition"/>
                <contained>
                    <HealthcareService>
                        <providedBy>
                            <reference>
                                <xsl:attribute name="value" namespace="" select="'#'"/>
                            </reference>
                        </providedBy>
                        <xsl:for-each select="$var1_actDefinition/ns0:code">
                            <type>
                                <coding>
                                    <system>
                                        <xsl:attribute name="value" namespace="" select="xs:string(xs:anyURI('http://ncicb.nci.nih.gov/xml/owl/EVS/Thesaurus.owl'))"/>
                                    </system>
                                    <code>
                                        <xsl:for-each select="@code">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="value" namespace="" select="fn:string(.)"/>
                                        </xsl:for-each>
                                    </code>
                                    <display>
                                        <xsl:for-each select="@displayName">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="value" namespace="" select="fn:string(.)"/>
                                        </xsl:for-each>
                                    </display>
                                </coding>
                            </type>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        <xsl:for-each select="$var1_actDefinition/ns0:subjectOf">
                            <serviceProvisionCode>
                                <xsl:for-each select="ns0:approval/ns0:code">
                                    <coding>
                                        <system>
                                            <xsl:attribute name="value" namespace="" select="xs:string(xs:anyURI('http://ncicb.nci.nih.gov/xml/owl/EVS/Thesaurus.owl'))"/>
                                        </system>
                                        <code>
                                            <xsl:for-each select="@code">
                                                <xsl:attribute name="value" namespace="" select="fn:string(.)"/>
                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                        </code>
                                        <display>
                                            <xsl:for-each select="@displayName">
                                                <xsl:attribute name="value" namespace="" select="fn:string(.)"/>
                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                        </display>
                                    </coding>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </serviceProvisionCode>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </HealthcareService>
                </contained>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="$var6_assignedEntity/ns0:assignedOrganization/ns0:assignedEntity/ns0:assignedOrganization/ns0:assignedEntity">
                <xsl:variable name="var3_cur" as="node()" select="."/>
                <xsl:for-each select="ns0:assignedOrganization">
                    <contained>
                        <xsl:for-each select="$var3_cur/ns0:performance/ns0:actDefinition/ns0:code">
                            <xsl:variable name="var2_resultof_createOrganizationAffiliation" as="node()?">
                                <xsl:call-template name="user:createOrganizationAffiliation">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="participatingId" select="'#usagent'" as="xs:string"/>
                                    <xsl:with-param name="SimpleCD" as="node()">
                                        <Simple-CD xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3">
                                            <xsl:call-template name="tbf:tbf2_Simple-CD">
                                                <xsl:with-param name="input" select="." as="node()"/>
                                            </xsl:call-template>
                                        </Simple-CD>
                                    </xsl:with-param>
                                </xsl:call-template>
                            </xsl:variable>
                            <xsl:for-each select="$var2_resultof_createOrganizationAffiliation">
                                <OrganizationAffiliation>
                                    <xsl:sequence select="(./@node(), ./node())"/>
                                </OrganizationAffiliation>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </contained>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="$var6_assignedEntity/ns0:assignedOrganization/ns0:assignedEntity/ns0:assignedOrganization/ns0:assignedEntity/ns0:assignedOrganization">
                <contained>
                    <Organization>
                        <id>
                            <xsl:attribute name="value" namespace="" select="'usagent'"/>
                        </id>
                        <xsl:for-each select="ns0:id">
                            <identifier>
                                <system>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="@root">
                                        <xsl:attribute name="value" namespace="" select="xs:string(xs:anyURI(fn:concat('urn:oid:', fn:string(.))))"/>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </system>
                                <value>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="@extension">
                                        <xsl:attribute name="value" namespace="" select="fn:string(.)"/>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </value>
                            </identifier>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        <type>
                            <coding>
                                <system>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="value" namespace="" select="$var7_http___hl__org_fhir_us_spl_Cod_as_string"/>
                                </system>
                                <code>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="value" namespace="" select="'USAgent'"/>
                                </code>
                            </coding>
                        </type>
                        <xsl:for-each select="ns0:name">
                            <name>
                                <xsl:for-each select="(./node())[fn:boolean(self::text())]">
                                    <xsl:attribute name="value" namespace="" select="fn:string(.)"/>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </name>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        <xsl:for-each select="ns0:telecom">
                            <xsl:variable name="var4_resultof_parseTelecom" as="node()?">
                                <xsl:call-template name="user:parseTelecom">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="SimpleTEL" as="node()">
                                        <Simple-TEL xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3">
                                            <xsl:sequence select="(./@node(), ./node())"/>
                                        </Simple-TEL>
                                    </xsl:with-param>
                                </xsl:call-template>
                            </xsl:variable>
                            <xsl:for-each select="$var4_resultof_parseTelecom">
                                <telecom>
                                    <xsl:sequence select="(./@node(), ./node())"/>
                                </telecom>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </Organization>
                </contained>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="$LabelerOrganization/ns0:id">
                <identifier>
                    <system>
                        <xsl:for-each select="@root">
                            <xsl:attribute name="value" namespace="" select="xs:string(xs:anyURI(fn:concat('urn:oid:', fn:string(.))))"/>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </system>
                    <value>
                        <xsl:for-each select="@extension">
                            <xsl:attribute name="value" namespace="" select="fn:string(.)"/>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </value>
                </identifier>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <type>
                <coding>
                    <system>
                        <xsl:attribute name="value" namespace="" select="$var7_http___hl__org_fhir_us_spl_Cod_as_string"/>
                    </system>
                    <code>
                        <xsl:attribute name="value" namespace="" select="'Labeler'"/>
                    </code>
                </coding>
            </type>
            <xsl:for-each select="$LabelerOrganization/ns0:name">
                <name>
                    <xsl:for-each select="(./node())[fn:boolean(self::text())]">
                        <xsl:attribute name="value" namespace="" select="fn:string(.)"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </name>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="$var6_assignedEntity/ns0:assignedOrganization/ns0:assignedEntity/ns0:assignedOrganization/ns0:addr">
                <address>
                    <xsl:for-each select="ns0:streetAddressLine">
                        <line>
                            <xsl:for-each select="(./node())[fn:boolean(self::text())]">
                                <xsl:attribute name="value" namespace="" select="fn:string(.)"/>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </line>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <xsl:for-each select="ns0:city">
                        <city>
                            <xsl:for-each select="(./node())[fn:boolean(self::text())]">
                                <xsl:attribute name="value" namespace="" select="fn:string(.)"/>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </city>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <xsl:for-each select="ns0:state">
                        <state>
                            <xsl:for-each select="(./node())[fn:boolean(self::text())]">
                                <xsl:attribute name="value" namespace="" select="fn:string(.)"/>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </state>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <xsl:for-each select="ns0:postalCode">
                        <postalCode>
                            <xsl:for-each select="(./node())[fn:boolean(self::text())]">
                                <xsl:attribute name="value" namespace="" select="fn:string(.)"/>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </postalCode>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <xsl:for-each select="ns0:country">
                        <country>
                            <xsl:for-each select="(./node())[fn:boolean(self::text())]">
                                <xsl:attribute name="value" namespace="" select="fn:string(.)"/>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </country>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </address>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="$LabelerOrganization/ns0:contactParty">
                <contact>
                    <xsl:for-each select="ns0:contactPerson/ns0:name">
                        <name>
                            <text>
                                <xsl:for-each select="(./node())[fn:boolean(self::text())]">
                                    <xsl:attribute name="value" namespace="" select="fn:string(.)"/>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </text>
                        </name>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <xsl:for-each select="ns0:telecom">
                        <xsl:variable name="var5_resultof_parseTelecom" as="node()?">
                            <xsl:call-template name="user:parseTelecom">
                                <xsl:with-param name="SimpleTEL" as="node()">
                                    <Simple-TEL xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3">
                                        <xsl:sequence select="(./@node(), ./node())"/>
                                    </Simple-TEL>
                                </xsl:with-param>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:variable>
                        <xsl:for-each select="$var5_resultof_parseTelecom">
                            <telecom>
                                <xsl:sequence select="(./@node(), ./node())"/>
                            </telecom>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <xsl:for-each select="ns0:addr">
                        <address>
                            <xsl:for-each select="ns0:streetAddressLine">
                                <line>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="(./node())[fn:boolean(self::text())]">
                                        <xsl:attribute name="value" namespace="" select="fn:string(.)"/>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </line>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                            <xsl:for-each select="ns0:city">
                                <city>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="(./node())[fn:boolean(self::text())]">
                                        <xsl:attribute name="value" namespace="" select="fn:string(.)"/>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </city>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                            <xsl:for-each select="ns0:state">
                                <state>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="(./node())[fn:boolean(self::text())]">
                                        <xsl:attribute name="value" namespace="" select="fn:string(.)"/>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </state>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                            <xsl:for-each select="ns0:postalCode">
                                <postalCode>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="(./node())[fn:boolean(self::text())]">
                                        <xsl:attribute name="value" namespace="" select="fn:string(.)"/>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </postalCode>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                            <xsl:for-each select="ns0:country">
                                <country>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="(./node())[fn:boolean(self::text())]">
                                        <xsl:attribute name="value" namespace="" select="fn:string(.)"/>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </country>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </address>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </contact>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Organization>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="vmf:vmf8_inputtoresult">
        <xsl:param name="input" select="()"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$input='tel'">
                <xsl:copy-of select="'phone'"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$input='mailto'">
                <xsl:copy-of select="'email'"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$input='fax'">
                <xsl:copy-of select="'fax'"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy-of select="'url'"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" byte-order-mark="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Bundle xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <type>
                <xsl:attribute name="value" namespace="" select="'collection'"/>
            </type>
            <xsl:for-each select="ns0:document/ns0:author/ns0:assignedEntity/ns0:representedOrganization">
                <xsl:variable name="var1_resultof_createLabelerOrganization" as="node()?">
                    <xsl:call-template name="user:createLabelerOrganization">
                        <xsl:with-param name="LabelerOrganization" as="node()">
                            <LabelerRequest.LabelerOrganization xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3">
                                <xsl:sequence select="(./@node(), ./node())"/>
                            </LabelerRequest.LabelerOrganization>
                        </xsl:with-param>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:for-each select="$var1_resultof_createLabelerOrganization">
                    <entry>
                        <resource>
                            <Organization>
                                <xsl:sequence select="(./@node(), ./node())"/>
                            </Organization>
                        </resource>
                    </entry>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Bundle>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You can install `xslt3` from NPM and then use it, it is an XSLT 3 processor, that, contrary to an XSLT 1 processor, does know how to use `xsl:sequence` and other XSLT 2/3 only instructions in your XSLT 2 code that an XSLT 1.0 processor will just ignore if it encounters `version="2.0" and processes in forwards compatible mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stylesheet specifies `version="2.0"`, and it uses some constructs that require XSLT 2.0, for example `select="()"`.

An XSLT 1.0 processor is going to handle this in "forwards-compatible mode". This is an area of the W3C spec that isn't always implemented very accurately, but in essence, an XSLT 1.0 processor seeing a 2.0 stylesheet is supposed to ignore things it doesn't understand. That means, for example that when you write `<xsl:attribute name="code" select="fn:string(.)"/>`, it will ignore the `select` attribute and output an attribute with the value "".

The other problem you can get with stylesheets generated by Altova Mapforce is that they contain calls to Altova-specific extensions functions. But I don't see any examples of that here -- as far as I can tell, this code should execute under a standard XSLT 2.0 processor such as Saxon. If you want to run this in node.js, try installing SaxonJS [disclaimer, this is my company's product].